# Audience network mediation via admob

Tags: android, admob, facebook-audience-network

In my Android App, I am trying to have the mediation to Facebook audience network via Admob. I checked my coding for the admob part. It is fine. But when I checked the Facebook performance details It has the filled - 162 but the impression as 27. I wonder what happened to the 135 impression.

Please let me know If I need to take care anything in specific when we do a mediation from admob to facebook

**FAN**
[image]

**Admob**
[image]

Comment: You've requested 214 ads, 162 of those requests were filled, only 27 of those 162 ads were actually presented to the user. So, for example, if your app requests an ad at launch, that counts as a request. If the FBAN gives your app an ad, that counts as an ad being filled. When your app actually presents the ad to the user that counts as an impression. You're either requesting too many ads, or are not presenting the ads as often as you think.

Answer (score 0):

Daniel Storm is correct. AdMob counts an impression as soon as it returns an ad from its server, Audience Network counts an impression once an impression has been considered 'viewable' on the client.